# How do I disable an swf object using javascript? e.g swfObject.disabled = true;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I want to basically do something like this

```
<div id="mySwfParent">
   <swfObject></swfObject>
</div>
```

Then later on some event I do this

```
document.getElementById('mySwfParent').disabled = true;
```

But this has no effect on the swfObject, it still responds to mouse events.

How do I disable an swf object using javascript or prevent it from responding to mouse events?

Comment: What kind of swf is that? Game or something?

Comment: Why dont you just hide the containing div?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli thats not an option right now

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend placing a transparent div over the entire area of the swf, effectively blocking the swf from mouse interaction. Be aware that you'll need to play around with the wmode parameter of the swf. Try setting it to both opaque and transparent.

Comment: How do I change the wmode at runtime? The swf is embedded dynamically with `swfobject.embedSWF()`. I need the swf object to be clickable initially

Comment: When you embed the swf with swfobject.embedSWF(), you can set the parameter, i.e: swfobject.embedSwf(..., ..., { wmode:'transparent'}). The swf will still be clickable if you initially have the transparent div set to display:none. Then just change its display property via JavaScript at the appropriate time.